# making files case insensitive at startup

Tags: 12.10, filesystem

I would like to have the files on my hard drives always be displayed case insensitive; i.e., from start-up every time. What is the easiest to do this? I am new to Linux and Ubuntu but am learning quickly, using 12.10.

I want to have my mp3 files in the GUI be listed purely alphabetically: AaBbCc, not ABCabc as they appear now. If there's a way to make file names all one case, I'd do that. I have files for bands beginning in both upper and lower case for the same bands; thousands of them. I want the band names to appear in one group.

Comment: I want to have my mp3 files in the GUI be listed purely alphabetically: AaBbCc, not ABCabc as they appear now. If there's a way to make file names all one case, I'll do that. I have files for bands beginning in both upper and lower case for the same bands, thousands of them. I want the band names to appear in one group.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Debian introductory tutorials](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch01.en.html#_unix_file_basics):

> UNIX filenames are case-sensitive.

Sorry, you're stuck with it.

There are some *extreme* hacks you could pull with [ciopfs](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/) (originally meant for [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)), but they'll affect your whole system (*read: break **everything***). At such a point it's more productive to complain to your music app's developers.

Comment: There's no environment variable I can set in a script somewhere? LC_COLLATE? ciopfs command? I'm not exactly sure how these things work, have just been poking around on Google.

Comment: I should add that I just want to display the files in this manner; i.e., AaBbCc, etc.

Comment: Do not put this information in the comments to an answer. Add them to the question, so the question is clarified.

Comment: @user Locale and filesystem hacks will likely break everything else. I've edited the answer to explain them.

Answer (score 2):

The `LC_COLLATE` environment variable determines sorting. If it is set to `POSIX` then files sort in a case-sensitive manner. Setting it to something human (like `en_GB.UTF-8`) will sort alphabetically without respect for case.

Execute `locale` in a command shell to see your current settings. Set your locale by picking it when logging in to your Unity session. Set the system locale in `/etc/default/locale`.

Note that if `LC_COLLATE` is not set, then `LANG` is the fallback default. You may want to set that instead. Note also that if `LC_ALL` is set to some value, then it will override `LC_COLLATE`.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your comment, you'd be content with making file names of mp3s all lower case. You can do this from command line with:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *.mp3
```

Rename is based on the Perl scripting language and should be installed by default on your Ubuntu.